# C# How to iterate an objects properties after they have been set from within the object itself?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to have a method inside of the object that will return a dictionary list of all it's property names and values dynamically after they have been initialized via the constructor. Something like this:

```
    public string name;
    public string type;

    public obj(string name, string type)
    {
        this.name = determineName(name)
        this.type = determineType(type)
        this.DictionaryOfValues = createDictionaryOfValues;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> createDictionaryOfValues(){
        // iterate name and type above dynamically and return a dictionary
        // with key value as property name and value
    }
```

I have seen examples of how to easily do it when the object already created but I'm wondering if there is some way to pick and return the values inside the object itself

Comment: Do you specifically want to do this dynamically without having to specify the field names?  If so that would involve using Reflection.  (Which will be a good bit slower than directly referencing the fields, if performance is important here.)

Comment: How did you do it with the object already created? If you can do it from an instance of the object, you can access the instance of the current object with `this`. eg:  if it's `var myObj = new obj(); var dict = makeDict(obj);`  you can instead do inside `createDictionaryOfValues() { return makeDict(this); }`.

Comment: @David, it's really not all that hard to make reflection performant if you care to.  (typically using expression trees, `Compile()`, and caching.)

Comment: @David I would like to do it dynamically to make things cleaner. Some fields are optional and there are a large number of fields. I can do a check if not null and grab them all in a single foreach loop if it supports doing it within the object itself

Comment: `this.GetType().GetProperties()`, knock yourself out. (Although note that you've specifically declared *fields*, here.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me. You can filter the fields further with custom attributes.

```
var fields = from fieldInfo in this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
let attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType < CustomAttribute > ()
where attributes.Any()
select new {
  fieldInfo.FieldType, fieldInfo.Name, Attribute = attributes.Single(), ar = fieldInfo.GetValue(this)
};

foreach(var field in fields) {
  Console.WriteLine(field.FieldType + " is called " +
    field.Name + " and its value is " +
    field.ar.ToString());
}
```